# "There is/has got to be an explanation." -- which verb to use there?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, auxiliary-verbs

I just came across the following sentence;

> There has got to be an explanation.

I think *has* has been wrongly/mistakenly used there and should better be replaced with *is*.

Comment: So what is your suggested sentence that you think is correct?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original sentence. *There* ***is got*** *to be* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Neeku "There has to be an explanation."

Comment: But what you're saying in your sentence is that: "... should better be replaced with *is*."?

Comment: I mean to ask which verb would be prefered if have to be used while feeling the need of no verb in there! ^^

Comment: Similar question had been asked on english.stackexchange.com link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152825/what-does-has-got-to-be-mean The answer is quite precise and I fail to find if the phrase is grammatical or formal.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the only answer that actually deals thoroughly with your question. I wonder why. Jason has also told you that is got is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"There is got to be"* makes no sense and is grammatically incorrect. And there are no records of such a phrase in N-grams. [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20has%20got%20to%20be%2Cthere%20is%20got%20to%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20has%20got%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0)

*"There has got to be"* is an informal way of saying "There must be".

You use have got to when you are saying that something is necessary or must happen in the way stated. In informal American English, the 'have' is sometimes omitted. *[spoken]*

- I'm not happy with the situation, but I've just got to accept it.
- There has got to be a degree of flexibility.
- See, you got to work very hard.

**Reference:** [Definition of 'have got to do sth'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-got-to-do-something) on [www.collinsdictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com)

*However, it would be better to use "must be" in formal texts.* Reference: [you have (got) to be kidding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-have-got-to-be-kidding)

Comment: "There has got to be" and "There has to be" are 100% the same thing. Has is not wrong and cannot be replaced by is. There is x means something else.  And your own answer doesn't even deal with your suggestion to replace has with is.

Answer (score 3):

"**There has got to be** an explanation." is exactly the same thing as:
"**There has to be** an explanation."

The reason? English has two forms to say the same thing. They both mean: ***There must be*** an explanation.

**"There is** an explanation." cannot take: have to and means something different.

**"There is an explanation."** means: An explanation exists for something [present tense].

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+has+got+to+be%2CThere+has+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20has%20got%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20has%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ZeeshanAli I'm afraid that does not provide an explanation. My explanation is correct. Yes, sometimes people out the have in have got.

Answer (score 0):

There has got to be an explanation.
This sentence is grammatically correct.

> There has got to be=there must be